# React Hook Form Controller with dynamic items issue

Tags: react-native, react-hook-form

I'm trying to implement dropdown component in react-native which is relying on react-hook-form.

So:

```js
<Controller
    as={
            <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text>1234</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
    }
    onChangeName={'onPress'}
    onChange={(item) => console.log('clicked!')}
    control={control}
    name={name}
/>
```

Works as intended

But in case of multiple elements it doesn't work:

```js
<Controller
    as={
       <>
           {options.map((item) => {
               <TouchableOpacity>
                   <Text>{item.text}</Text>
               </TouchableOpacity>
           })}
       </>
    onChangeName={'onPress'}
    onChange={(item) => console.log('clicked!')}
    control={control}
    name={name}
/>
```

I understand that's probably Controller is trying to bind his "onChange" event with top component  which is in this case just a wrapper, is there any way to specify that's Controller "onChange" event supposed to be binded to child components?

Comment: I think this one of the mistakes we did in v5, in v6 we are exposing render prop which making things much easier and predictable.

Comment: Thanks, i totally forgot that i'm using v5. render prop is exactly what i'm looking for